# PHP: move_uploaded_file() failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I'm trying to get PHP to move an uploaded file from the tmp directory to somewhere permanent on my webserver. It seems simple enough, but I'm getting this error:

`Unable to move 'C:\UniServer\tmp\php3F62.tmp' to 'static/images/slides/1/1.jpg'`

Pretty straight-forward, right? It can't find the destination folder.

My question is: **How do I reference the desired target directory?**

Is the reference relative to the script's position on the server? Or is it relative to the URL? Or the `PHP DOCUMENT_ROOT`? Or the OS's filesystem? Or something else?

I can't find the answer in the PHP documentation or indeed in any of the similar questions here on SO..

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: It's form the script's position on the server. Best use an absolute path at all times

Comment: use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant on paths to make it platform independent.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A simple way to keep track of the path is just to define the absolute path in your index.php

```
define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Then just use it like:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], SITE_ROOT.'/static/images/slides/1/1.jpg');
```

Comment: This is how I do it as well. It's better than using the doc root because this way, you can have your app in a sub-dir

Comment: This is the right solution, thanks! (It's kind of worrying that several people thought that DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR would help, though :-/ )

Comment: Ive never used it, id only use it if i was going to output the path to the user. Thanks for the accept :)

Comment: just a doubt... isn't it
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
instead of
    $_FILES['file']['temp_name']

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: Thanks for this useful tip. My form will working now.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem  with my uploading. See my example and maybe it can help you.

The file that I created is named "uploads".

```
$uploads_dir = 'uploads/';
$name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
{       
    //in case you want to move  the file in uploads directory
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir.$name);
     echo 'moved file to destination directory';
     exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is from the script's position on the server! And moreover, you need to have write permissions in this folder:

```
'static/images/slides/1/1.jpg'
```

Instead it is better to use an absolute path this way:

```
'C:\UniServer\***\static\images\slides\1\1.jpg
```

Use an absolute path.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Thanks for the info, but just to be extra careful, knowing the OS. :)

Comment: No idea, but maybe because you still have erroneous information about Windows in there? I got a downvote on the question, too.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

```
$destination = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))."/runtime/tmp/";
chown($destination, 0755);
move_uploaded_file($info['tmp_name'], $destination.$info['name']);
```

This is my solution, I just use mkdir to create a directory to put my picture which I want to move.
Wish it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you without giving you any error:

```
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_temp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$target='C:/xampp/htdocs/jer/images/'.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($image_temp, "$target");
insert into images (images) values ('$target');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` before the name of the destination of your file. It will add an absolute location of your project on the server so the file can be upload in the exact location that you want.

Example of code

`$ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

`$file_name = time() . "-" . rand(100000, 1000000) . "." . $ext;`

`$destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage/uploads/' . $file_name;`

`$res = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destination);`