# move_uploaded_file() failed to open stream: no such file or directory

Tags: php, file-upload

I've done your standard checks (is the directory there, are lax enough permissions set), and I'm pretty sure I've covered your standard stupid human tricks. Here's the code that's failing:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], "/public_html/flashsale/assets/img/products/T".$_FILES['image1']['name']);
```

The directory is there - I copied the path from *FileZilla*. I even set the permissions to **777**, both in FileZilla and in the file manager on the *HostGator* control panel. This code generates two warnings:

> Message:
>   move_uploaded_file(/public_html/flashsale/assets/img/products/Tsirloin.jpg)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory
>
> Message: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move '/tmp/phpI5GZ3S' to
>   '/public_html/flashsale/assets/img/products/Tsirloin.jpg'

In that order. So, the file is being uploaded, the directory exists and is set to 777, what else could I be missing?

Comment: Don't always use absolute path. Or make sure the path from root folder to the images folder is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: move\_uploaded\_file() failed to open stream: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951334/php-move-uploaded-file-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you do not need to put the full directory to the file. try to remove `/public_html/flashsale/` from your link and see if that will work.
In addition, the file does not need to have 777 permission, I myself upload files to folders with 755 permissions.

also, you can use `getcwd();` in the directory your aiming to. the function will give you the directory that you need to use for moving your file. [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Turns out I wasn't using the /home/user/ part of the path - adding getcwd() fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

**The Problem**

```
$dirpath = dirname(getcwd())
```

This is what I used initially to get the directory path to my /public_html/upload folder. $dirpath will contain

```
/public_html/upload
```

**The Solution(On server)**

```
$dirpath = realpath(dirname(getcwd()))
```

Since I’m on a shared hosting environment, the right way of getting move_uploaded_file to work is using this as the destination:
realpath(dirname(getcwd())) returns something like:

```
/home/cpanelusername/public_html/upload
```

Comment: Thanks this saved me :) (y)

Comment: gud luck programming Ajmal...(Y)

Comment: You explained this well but you didn't put the sample code, where should I put the $dirpath variable?

Comment: When do you want to upload files into your server..Then you need a file uploading path(Folder path in server).So If you can not get it correctly Then you should be errors on your page..So I have mentioned here to get real folder path method..I got a solution by this methode..You also can try this friend.. :) @samouray

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 14.04 with XAMPP, I also have problem with upload but after I have fixed with `sudo chmod -R 777 destination`, it works well.

Here is what I did:

Temporary folder to upload in my Ubuntu 14.04 XAMPP is /opt/lampp/temp/. If I want my upload files to `/opt/lampp/temp/testupload` as destination folder, then I need config bellow.

1. Go to temp folder

   ```
   cd /opt/lampp/temp/
   ```
2. Create 'testupload' folder under /opt/lampp/temp/

   ```
   sudo mkdir testupload
   ```
3. Change permission 777

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/temp/testupload/
   ```
4. PHP code

   ```
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/opt/lampp/temp/testupload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the path you are traversing. public_html is not required

```
$image=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$image=str_replace(' ','|',$image);

$tmppath="images/".$image;

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$tmppath))
        {
         echo "success";
        }
        else
        {
         echo "fail";
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I was searching like several hours for this solution, didn't know why $_FILES['file']['name'] was empty all the time when I was trying to push the file name. Thanks sir !!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Windows and ISS:

The IUSR account needed permissions in the destination directory. Not the ISS_IUSR account, just the IUSR account.