# Uploading multifiles

Tags: php, html

I can't upload multiple files. I have a table of 4 items, each may have an uploaded file.

How should the code be?

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
    foreach ($_FILES as $f => $a) {
        if ($a["name"]) {
            $target_file = $target_dir . "paper_" . $id . "_" . $f[12];
            $file_name = basename($a["name"]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
             && $imageFileType != "pdf" && $imageFileType != "doc" && $imageFileType != "docx") {
                echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, PDF, DOC and DOCX files are allowed. Your type is $imageFileType ";
                continue;
            }
            if ($a["size"] > 1024 * 1024 * 4) {
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large. Max is 4 MB";
                continue;
            }
            $col = "";
            switch ($f[12]) {
                case 1:
                    $col = "path_salary_def";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $col = "path_social";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $col = "path_identification";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $col = "path_accom";
                    break;
                default:
                    die("invalid column");
            }
            $bol = substr($col, 5);
            if (move_uploaded_file($a["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                $query = "update papers SET $col = '$target_file', $bol = 1 WHERE id = " . $id;
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("Error in the data table 5");
                echo "The file $file_name has been uploaded.<br/>";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Your poor system forces me to add more details while my question ended. I have to copy-paste some text so that it accepts it.... what a bad site

Comment: Learn something from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Comment: @andrew the loop don't even work. `$_FILES` is empty

Comment: The system is like that so we can help you better

Comment: `$_FILES` is empty? well, then of course the loop wont work, perhaps you should edit the question showing your form. does it have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? because its required to post files

Comment: Here's an answer already written about how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php

Comment: @andrew no, it doesn't have. Let me try...

Comment: @andrew Can you put your comment as an answer? I'd like to choose as best one!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `$_FILES` array is empty perhaps  you omitted the `enctype` attribute form the form.

It should look like:

```
<form action="yourAction.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Must the method be `"POST/GET"` too??

Comment: I can't find any thing to confirm this I'd stick with `method ="POST"`

Comment: Actually, it must be POST.

Comment: now it says `Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/paper_4_1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\showroom_papers_save.php on line 79

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php5E05.tmp' to 'uploads/paper_4_1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\showroom_papers_save.php on line 79
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.`

Comment: you should be moving the file from `['tmp_name']` element in the files array, do a `var_dump($_FILES)` you'll see what I mean, also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596832/move-uploaded-file-failed-to-open-stream)

Comment: Thank you very much... I needed to change `$target_dir = "/uploads/";` to `$target_dir = "../uploads/";`