# Cannot upload multiple images to SQL database via PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

Recently, I've tried to insert into my database some records containing of text and images. While text is inserted without a problem, images can't go in. The images I try to insert are not heavy. It's on usual only few kb.
Did I make some mistakes in my .php file?

```
<?php

// php code to Insert data into mysql database from input text
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $databaseName = "database1";
    // get values form input text and number
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $contact1 = $_POST['contact1'];
      $contact2 = $_POST['contact2'];
     $filename = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
  $filetmpname = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
   $filename2 = $_FILES['uploadfile2']['name'];
  $filetmpname2 = $_FILES['uploadfile2']['tmp_name'];
  $folder = 'imagesuploadedf/';
   $folder = 'imagesuploadedf2/';
  move_uploaded_file($filetmpname, $folder.$filename);
  move_uploaded_file($filetmpname2, $folder2.$filename2);
    $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
    // mysql query to insert data
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tabela`(`name`, `imagename`, `imagename2`, `contact1`, `contact2`) VALUES ('$fname', '$filename', '$filename2', '$contact1', '$contact2')";    
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    // check if mysql query successful
    if($result)
    {
        echo 'Data Inserted';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Data Not Inserted';
    }   
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> PHP INSERT DATA </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="fname"  placeholder="First Name"><br><br>
           <input type="file" name="uploadfile" ><br><br>
            <input type="file" name="uploadfile2" ><br><br>
                 <input type="text" name="contact1"  placeholder="Contact1"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="contact2"  placeholder="Contact2"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add Data To Database">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: does actual images get uploaded in folder 1 and folder 2 ?

Comment: `$folder` is overridden think the second line should be `$folder2 = 'imagesuploadedf2/';`

Comment: it should be  $folder = 'imagesuploadedf/';
   $folder2 = 'imagesuploadedf2/';

Comment: @DrMJ  yes sure, Is it wrong?

Comment: Also you should get a warning, that folder2 is undefined

Comment: Your form should have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute

Comment: @JonathanCrane No ..it is not wrong.. I am asking if images are getting uploaded in folder and Only its link is not getting added in db or Both things are not happening....

Comment: @DrMJ None of these things happen. It is only a spare space in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
<?php

 // php code to Insert data into mysql database from input text
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databaseName = "database1";
// get values form input text and number
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $contact1 = $_POST['contact1'];
  $contact2 = $_POST['contact2'];
  $filename = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
  $filetmpname = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
  $filename2 = $_FILES['uploadfile2']['name'];
  $filetmpname2 = $_FILES['uploadfile2']['tmp_name'];
  $folder = 'imagesuploadedf/';
  $folder2 = 'imagesuploadedf2/';

 // edited and added below code. it will check if folder exists and create if not exists.....
 $foldername = 'imagesuploadedf';
 $foldername2 = 'imagesuploadedf2';
 if ( ! is_dir($foldername)) {
     mkdir($foldername);
 }
 if ( ! is_dir($foldername2)) {
    mkdir($foldername2);
  }
 // end of edited and added code


  move_uploaded_file($filetmpname, $folder.$filename);
  move_uploaded_file($filetmpname2, $folder2.$filename2);
  $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
  // mysql query to insert data
$query = "INSERT INTO `tabela`(`name`, `imagename`, `imagename2`, `contact1`, `contact2`) VALUES ('$fname', '$filename', '$filename2', '$contact1', '$contact2')";    
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
// check if mysql query successful
 if($result)
 {
     echo 'Data Inserted';
 }
 else{
    echo 'Data Not Inserted';
 }   
 mysqli_free_result($result);
  mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
     <title> PHP INSERT DATA </title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
 <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="fname"  placeholder="First Name"><br><br>
       <input type="file" name="uploadfile" ><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="uploadfile2" ><br><br>
             <input type="text" name="contact1"  placeholder="Contact1"><br><br>
                <input type="text" name="contact2"  placeholder="Contact2"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add Data To Database">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Are folders viz `imagesuploadedf` and `imagesuploadedf2` created ?

Also be careful and sanitize input data before adding to db.

Comment: again error: Warning: move_uploaded_file(imagesuploadedf/am.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp2\htdocs\index.php on line 51

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp2\tmp\php206F.tmp' to 'imagesuploadedf/am.png' in C:\xampp2\htdocs\index.php on line 51

Warning: move_uploaded_file(imagesuploadedf2/c2.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp2\htdocs\index.php on line 52

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp2\tmp\php2070.tmp' to 'imagesuploadedf2/c2.png' in C:\xampp2\htdocs\index.php on line 52

Comment: Are folders viz imagesuploadedf and imagesuploadedf2 created ? are they in root folder or in subfolder ?

Comment: I am sorry what folders? arent they created automatically? I am sorry but I am only a beginner in PHP:( Can you send me a link or explain how and where to create them?

Answer (score 0):

Please add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag

like `<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: I have this error: Warning: move_uploaded_file(imagesuploadedf/a.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp2\htdocs\index.php on line 51

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp2\tmp\php5BD7.tmp' to 'imagesuploadedf/a.png' in C:\xampp2\htdocs\index.php on line 51

Warning: move_uploaded_file(imagesuploadedf2/i2.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp2\htdocs\index.php on line 52

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp2\tmp\php5BD8.tmp' to 'imagesuploadedf2/i2.png' in C:\xampp2\htdocs\index.php on line 52

Comment: You can check [This Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596832/move-uploaded-file-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)