# php file uploading cannot retrieve the path

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I am trying to upload photos in to folder uploads and its path to be recorded under photo in DB. This is my code:

```
$folder ="uploads";
$destFile = $folder . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
$sourdeFile = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];


if(move_uploaded_file($sourdeFile,$destFile)){
    echo "File has been uploaded";
    $photo = $destFile;
}else{
    echo $_FILES['photo']['error'];
    $photo = "images/default.png";
}
```

When I upload photos they successfully uploaded into folder but the problem is its path recorded as follow :

```
uploads42141402_1866830986743601_8538143552767524864_n.jpg
```

But to view photos in a page there should be `\` next to uploads. So I tried to change my code as follow.

```
$folder = "uploads\";
```

But it generates [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BFpO.png)

Can anyone say how to fix this ?

Comment: You have the wrong slash \ should be /

Comment: i did it too.But still same error

Comment: have you given read-write permission to the upload folder? also, check the uploads folder should be inside carsale/controller folder

Comment: i did it too.Moved the folder into controller folder and change.but error is till same

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$folder ="uploads/";
```

I've tried and it works. Maybe `$folder ="uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;` will better than "/".

Comment: Ahhh, I got why. How about [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951334/php-move-uploaded-file-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

For the error its looks uploads folder is not there or it not have permission

create a upload folder or try with absolute path

you can make use of `dirname(__FILE__) or $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for creating dynamic path